# How Can I Count malloc in linux kernel with kprobe

Tags: linux-kernel, malloc, system-calls, fedora, kprobe

I want to count the `malloc` system call with Kprobe in fedora.
I know that `malloc` is not a system call and is implemented in user space, but I want to count malloc with kprobe if its possible.

What is the name of system call that I must give to Kprobe?
For example for do_work:

```
kp.addr = (kprobe_opcode_t *) kallsyms_lookup_name("do_fork");
```

Comment: `malloc` is *not* a system call. In the GNU Glibc library, it is implemented using the `mmap` and `sbrk` syscalls. Maybe you want to use `valgrind` on your user application.... The kernel itself is allocating dynamic memory (inside the kernel, not for applications) using `kmalloc` and related kernel functions.

Comment: And you can also use `pmap` and, for process of pid 1234, look into `/proc/1234/status` and `/proc/1234/maps` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with kprobes because, as you said, `malloc` is not a system call.

You can, however, use USDTs to trace userspace processes. [The bcc tools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) contain an example with [`uobjnew`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/lib/uobjnew.py). It traces object allocations in the given process:

```
$ ./uobjnew -h
usage: uobjnew.py [-h] [-l {java,ruby,c}] [-C TOP_COUNT] [-S TOP_SIZE] [-v]
                  pid [interval]

Summarize object allocations in high-level languages.

positional arguments:
  pid                   process id to attach to
  interval              print every specified number of seconds

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l {java,ruby,c}, --language {java,ruby,c}
                        language to trace
  -C TOP_COUNT, --top-count TOP_COUNT
                        number of most frequently allocated types to print
  -S TOP_SIZE, --top-size TOP_SIZE
                        number of largest types by allocated bytes to print
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode: print the BPF program (for debugging
                        purposes)

examples:
    ./uobjnew -l java 145         # summarize Java allocations in process 145
    ./uobjnew -l c 2020 1         # grab malloc() sizes and print every second
    ./uobjnew -l ruby 6712 -C 10  # top 10 Ruby types by number of allocations
    ./uobjnew -l ruby 6712 -S 10 # top 10 Ruby types by total size
```