# How to get notified on each memory allocation/deallocation?

Tags: kernel, process, memory, process-management, virtual-memory

I want to make a module that will analyze memory usage of different processes. my idea was to parse `ps -eo pid,vsz,rss`. But I was wondering if it is possible to make the kernel call my module on each memory allocation/deallocation. Is it possible in andriod x86?

Comment: perhaps you're looking for advice on modifying the Linux kernel. In this case, you're better off on stackoverflow. However, do some initial research on modifying and recompiling the kernel -- and only then ask a specific question there. We already have some (closed) questions on how to get started with Kernel programming. Hope this helps.

Comment: Use malloc debug ?  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/malloc_debug/README.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Count malloc in linux kernel with kprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476325/how-can-i-count-malloc-in-linux-kernel-with-kprobe)