# Track malloc function calls using kernel module with kprobes on mmap and brk

Tags: linux, module, kernel, malloc, kprobe

I am trying to see how many times is the malloc function called in userspace using a kernel module and kprobes on mmap and brk. I found the system calls inside the kernel as sys_mmap and sys_brk, but when I try to insert the module inside the kernel it says:

> insmod: can't insert mallocmonitor.ko. Operation not permitted

Also, when I register a kprobe on __kmalloc, kfree, or map_region functions it works without any problem.

Does anyone has an insight on this?

Comment: Try [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476325/how-can-i-count-malloc-in-linux-kernel-with-kprobe).  You can't use kprobes directly since malloc is a library function rather than a syscall, but BCC will allow you to probe syscalls of your malloc implementation (or USDTs of a specific program if you prefer) as documented in its reference guide:  [BCC refguide](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md#8-system-call-tracepoints).  Lots of code examples there.

Comment: Thank you! I'll will look it up.